# Error Code : 1064 while trying to retrieve values between timestamps

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, unix-timestamp

In my table, I have entries *(with datetime datatype)* like:

[image]

and I need result between a specific UNIX time stamp. When I run the query:

```
Select ifnull(ji.JobID,'') as JobID, ifnull(ji.ReelIndex,'') as ReelIndex, ifnull(ji.FileName,'') as FileName, 
 ifnull(ji.MediaType,'') as MediaType, ifnull(ji.QCStatus,'') as QCStatus, ifnull(ji.QCComments,'') as QCComments, 
 ifnull(ji.PackagingStatus,'') as PackagingStatus, ci.Name 
from job_info as ji 
left join content_info as ci on 
 ji.ContainerID = ci.ID 
where ji.Progress = 100 
where ji.ProcessStartTime >= 1449081000 
  and ji.ProcessEndTime <= 1450549800 
order by Name asc, ReelIndex asc 
LIMIT 0 , 20
```

it throws an error:

> Error Code : 1064    You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
> syntax to use near 'where ji.ProcessStartTime >= 1449081000 and
> ji.ProcessEndTime <= 1450549800    or' at line 4

What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have double `WHERE` use `AND/OR` instead:

```
SELECT ifnull(ji.JobID,'') AS JobID,
       ifnull(ji.ReelIndex,'') AS ReelIndex,
       ifnull(ji.FileName,'') AS FileName,
       ifnull(ji.MediaType,'') AS MediaType,
       ifnull(ji.QCStatus,'') AS QCStatus,
       ifnull(ji.QCComments,'') AS QCComments,
       ifnull(ji.PackagingStatus,'') AS PackagingStatus,
       ci.Name
FROM job_info AS ji
LEFT JOIN content_info AS ci 
  ON ji.ContainerID = ci.ID
WHERE ji.Progress = 100 
  AND ji.ProcessStartTime >= FROM_UNIXTIME(1449081000)     -- here 
  AND ji.ProcessEndTime <= FROM_UNIXTIME(1450549800)
ORDER BY Name ASC, ReelIndex ASC 
LIMIT 0, 20;
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to skip time part and set it to `00:00:00` `CAST` to `DATE`:

```
...
AND CAST(ji.ProcessStartTime AS DATE) >= FROM_UNIXTIME(1449081000)     
AND CAST(ji.ProcessEndTime AS DATE) <= FROM_UNIXTIME(1450549800)
```

Note also that you need to use [`FROM_UNIXTIME`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) to convert unix_timestamp to datetime.

Comment: Is there a way, I could consider only dates and not time while I query the database? `1449081000` corresponds to `2015-12-03`  and `1450549800` corresponds to `2015-12-20`. But the DB also has time with it. So the above query will always return an empty set.

Comment: @SuhailGupta See updated. `1449081000` -> `December, 02 2015 18:30:00` so it has time part too

Comment: Beautiful. But I would want to add that I had to use `from_unixtime(1449081000)` so that I could see result!